# Efficient tree data structure which doesn't allow duplicates on same level

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I'm developing a tree structure that should guarantee that each parent node contains only unique set of nodes. Here's my code:

```
public class TreeNode implements Iterable<TreeNode> {

    private final TreeNode parent;
    private final List<TreeNode> children = new LinkedList<>();

    public TreeNode(TreeNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public TreeNode append(TreeNode child) {
        int index = children.indexOf(child);
        if (index < 0) {
            children.add(child);
            return child;
        } else {
            return children.get(index);
        }
    }

    public Iterator<TreeNode> iterator() {
        return children.iterator();
    }

    /* Other unimportant application details */

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TreeNode t = (TreeNode) o;
        return parent != null ? parent.equals(t.parent) : t.parent == null;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return parent != null ? parent.hashCode() : 0;
    }

}
```

The problem here is that if my tree is to deep, Each `children.indexOf()` call will recursively check all parents equality on each `append` method call. I think of re-implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in a way that they will only check that immetiate parent is the same for each node on same level. Like so:

```
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TreeNode t = (TreeNode) o;
        return parent == t.parent;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return System.identityHashCode(parent);
    }
```

I can't think of the reasons why this could be a problem. Do you see any problems with this implementation? If so, can you suggest any better solutions of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

*"should guarantee that each parent node contains only unique set of nodes."*

As per my opinion, 
    private final List children = new LinkedList<>();

1. It should be Map, so that you can guarantee about the uniqueness of children nodes(provided you have implemented hashCode() and equals()).
2. If we take it as Map, then the append() call will be O(1) time complexity, which is O(n) in case of Lists.

If you have any other thoughts for defining children as List, then please share with us.

Comment: In my case the branches happens very rarely. The resulting tree structure is more deep than wide. Keeping linkedlist, in my opinion, is more efficient for this scenario. But thanks for your answer.